# SSL messages encoding

Tags: json, python-3.x, ssl, unicode, hex

I am trying to build an SSL Server under Python 3.4. The point is to communicate and exchange data with a programme through a defined protocol based on JSON data format.

So I used a basic "echo server" and client in SSL Protocol and modified those to see if I could exchange data. It worked and sending "hello" one side comes as b"hello" on the other side and it works both ways.

I start the server side, connect the program, it communicates succesfully, but:
I am expecting something like : `LOGIN:n::{“user”:”XXXXX”, , ”password”:”YYYYY ”, app”:”ZZZZZ”, “app_ver”:”zzz”, ”protocol”:”xxx”,”protocol_ver”:”xxxx”}` arriving from the client (program)

But instead I am getting something like this `b"\x16\x03\x03\x00\x8e\x01\x00\x00\x8a\x03\x03^\x9e\xeb\xd8\x8f\xd9 \x05v\xbbF:}\xda\x17\xf7\x13\xff\xa9\xde=5\xfb_\xbco\x16\x96EL#\x00\x00*\xc0,\xc0+\xc00\xc0/\x00\x9f\x00\x9e\xc0$\xc0#\xc0(\xc0'\xc0\n\xc0\t\xc0\x14\xc0\x13\x00\x9d\x00\x9c\x00=\x00<\x005\x00/\x00\n\x01\x00\x007\x00\n\x00\x08\x00\x06\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\r\x00\x14\x00\x12\x06\x01\x06\x03\x04\x01\x05\x01\x02\x01\x04\x03\x05\x03\x02\x03\x02\x02\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00"`

I thought it was simply encoded, but I have tried the `bytemessage.decode()`method, with utf-8, cp437, cp1250, cp1252, latin-1, etc. I have also tried codecs.decode() with hex. No success, I Don't understand what language is this.

I am new to SSL so I suppose I am missing something obvious here, but I have no idea what …

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

---- Edit here is the code of my server-----

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 5000)
print ('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
     print ( 'waiting for a connection')
     connection, client_address = sock.accept();
     try:
        print( 'connection from', client_address)
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print ( 'received "%s"' % data)
            if True:
                 #data2=b'{"timing":{"liveEvents": {"sector": {"dayTime": 1483523892618,"driver": 1,"isValid": false,"participant": "0","sector": 3,"time": -1}}}}'
                 print ('sending data to the client')
                 #connection.sendall(data2)
            else:
                print ( 'no more data from', client_address)
                break

     finally:
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> b"\x16\x03\x03...
> ```

This is a TLS message. Looks like your client tries to speak TLS to your server but your server cannot properly handle it. Instead of treating the data as TLS it will assume that the TLS is the actual application data.

Looking at your server code the reason is clear: you are not doing any SSL there, i.e. you are doing a plain TCP socket. SSL will not magically appear just because a clients tries to talk SSL with the server but you need to use the ssl module, properly `wrap_socket` and provide the necessary server certificate and key. For some simple example see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#socket-creation).

Comment: Thank you @Steffen for your answer, i will investigate TLS queries and why this one might not be handled. I have also edited my post with the server code ( it is really rudimentary)

Comment: Also looking back at my code, I can't see any mention of ssl, so it might just be a standard TCP/IP, and that message would be the SSL handshake attempt by the client

Comment: @OwenMarriott: yes, the problem is that you are  not handling SSL at all in your server.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steffen mentioned , I wasn't handling SSL at all, which I now do with `ssl.wrap_socket(sock,certfile='certificat.pem', keyfile='cle.pem', server_side=True)`

Operation on server side requires certificates and key files in pem, which I generated with SelfSSL7 and then split the pfx into 2 pem key and certificate files with OpenSSL

`openssl pkcs12 -in yourpfxfile.pfx -nocerts -out privatekey.pem -nodes 
 openssl pkcs12 -in yourpfxfile.pfx -nokeys -out publiccert.pem -nodes`

Maybe not the fastest solution for a self signed certificate since I now have OpenSSL installed but …

Finally, the expected message !!

```
starting up on localhost port 11000
waiting for a connection
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 60488)
received "b'PING:0::\r\n'"
sending data to the client
received "b'LOGIN:::{"user":"test","password":"test","app":"AppName","app_ver":"1.0.0","protocol":" ","protocol_ver":"1.0.0"}\r\n'"
sending data to the client
```

Again thank you very much @SteffenUllrich